# Having trouble dynamically show/hide DataGrid buttoncolumn based on record existing in SQL database using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and vb.net. I have a datagrid with several columns, the column in question is a ButtonColumn control. Currently buttons appear on every row then link to another page where data is displayed about the name (in another column) is selected.  The problem is when the query on the next page doesn't contain data for the selected row the page throws an error.

My (preferred) solution is to check that a record exists first during ItemDataBound event (before switching pages), and hide the button in rows where no record exists and show the button where they do. The problem is that the buttons are showing and hiding inconsistently.

I am not a vb programmer can someone review my code to see where I am going wrong.

I have consulted google and used these links to get some of this figured out:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8666/Practical-use-of-the-DataGrid-s-ItemDataBound-even

http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/WebDataGrid.aspx

**UPDATE:** The solution is updated in Code #1 and HTML where noted.
**SQL**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[VerifyRecords] 
    @Name VarChar (50),
    @RecordExists Int output
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

   SELECT top 1 * from tblRecords where Name = @Name

   If @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
    begin
        Select @RecordExists = 5 --record does not exist
    end
   else
    begin
        Select @RecordExists = 1  --record exists
    end  

    -- --ALTERNATIVE QUERY
    --if not exists (select 1 from tblRecords where Name = @Name)
    --  begin
    --      Select @RecordExists = 5    --print 'no record found'
    --  end
    --else
    --  begin 
    --      Select @RecordExists = 1    --print 'record exists'
    --  end
END

enter code here
```

1.**CODE** in calling class

```
Protected Sub DataGrid1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles DataGrid1.ItemDataBound

               If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then

                Dim strName As String = ""  
                Dim blnHasRecord As Boolean

                   ' *** UPDATED CODE HERE ***
                   Dim lblName As Label = e.Item.FindControl("lblName")
                   strName = lblName.Text.ToString()

                    Dim oRecord As DataAccessLib.SqlConn = New DataAccessLib.SqlConn()

                    blnHasRecord = oRecord.VerifyRecordExists(strName)
                    DirectCast(e.Item.Cells(9).Controls(0), Button).Visible = blnHasRecord              
            End If
        End Sub
```

2.**CODE** in Data Access Class

```
Function VerifyRecordExists (ByVal name As String) As Boolean

        Try

            Dim recordExists As Boolean

            Dim result As Int32  

            'connection
            Using conStr As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SomeConnectionString").ConnectionString)

                'open connection
                conStr.Open()

                'command
                Dim cmdVerifyRecordExists As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("VerifyRecordExists", conStr)
                cmdVerifyRecordExists.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

                'input parameter
                cmdVerifyRecordExists.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name

                'output parameter
                cmdVerifyRecordExists.Parameters.Add("@RecordExists", SqlDbType.Int)
                cmdVerifyRecordExists.Parameters("@RecordExists").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output 

                'execute query 
                cmdVerifyRecordExists.ExecuteNonQuery()
                result = cmdVerifyRecordExists.Parameters("@RecordExists").Value

            End Using

            If (name <> Nothing) Then  

                If (result = 5) Then 'result = 5; no records found
                    recordExists = False
                Else
                    ' result = 1; records found
                    recordExists = True
                    Return recordExists
                End If
            End If

        Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

            ' code here removed for breivity

        End Try
    End Function
```

3.**CODE** to bind DataGrid

```
Sub getRecords(ByVal strSortField As String)

    Dim sortdir As Integer

    DataGrid1.DataSource = Nothing

    Using conStr As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SomeConnectionString").ConnectionString)

        Try 
            If USERLEVEL > 2 Then 

                conStr.Open()

                Dim cmdSelectRecords As New SqlCommand("SelectAllNames", conStr)

                cmdSelectRecords.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure 

                SqlDataAdapter1.Fill(DsRecords1) 
                Dim objDataView As DataView = DsRecords1.Tables("vwRecordsList").DefaultView 

                DataGrid1.DataSource = Nothing 

                DataGrid1.DataSource = objDataView 

                If Session("sortdir") = Nothing Then
                    Session("sortdir") = 1  ' 1=ASC, 0=DESC
                Else
                    sortdir = Session("sortdir")
                End If

                If sortdir = 1 Then
                    Session("sortdir") = 0
                    objDataView.Sort = strSortField & " DESC"

                ElseIf sortdir = 0 Then
                    Session("sortdir") = 1
                    objDataView.Sort = strSortField & " ASC"

                End If

                DataGrid1.DataBind() 

            ElseIf USERLEVEL = 2 Then 

                Dim cmdSelectRecords As New SqlCommand("SelectNamesBySuper", conStr)

                cmdSelectRecords.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure   
                cmdSelectRecords.Parameters.Add("@UID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = uID 

                SqlDataAdapter1.Fill(DsRecords1)

                Dim objDataView As DataView = DsRecords1.Tables("vwRecordsList ").DefaultView

                DataGrid1.DataSource = Nothing
                DataGrid1.DataSource = objDataView

                If Session("sortdir") = Nothing Then
                    Session("sortdir") = 1

                Else
                    sortdir = Session("sortdir")

                End If

                If sortdir = 1 Then

                    Session("sortdir") = 0
                    objDataView.Sort = strSortField & " DESC"

                ElseIf sortdir = 0 Then

                    Session("sortdir") = 1
                    objDataView.Sort = strSortField & " ASC"

                End If

                DataGrid1.DataBind() 

            Else
                Response.Redirect("AccessDenied.aspx")

            End If
        Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
' error code left out for demo purposes
                End If

            End Try

        End Using

    End Sub
```

**HTML**
*I am only providing the pertinent column of DataGrid1 as the grid itself is loading just fine.  It's my modification to this column in code behind that isn't correct yet.*

**UPDATE**: I replaced boundcolumn with TemplateColumn:

```
<%--<asp:BoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText=" Name" SortExpression="Name" Visible="False" />--%>
<asp:TemplateColumn>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label id="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Comment: buttons are showing and hiding inconsistently when? After a page load or when somthng happend in page like push button.

Comment: On DirectCast try  GridItem.Cells(9).Controls(0) intead of change e.Item.Cells(9).Controls(0)

Comment: Oh nice @DanielVorph, this did the trick!  Please make it an answer and I will accept.  But now when the Name column is resorted, the first row, becomes the last row and it incorrectly displays a button when it should be hidden.  All other rows display button/no button correctly in ASC or DESC order. When I resort back to original (asc) sort, the first row is correct again.  I posted sort code #3 for this if interested in taking a look.

Comment: Put DirectCast(GridItem.Cells(9).Controls(0), Button).Visible = blnHasRecord quit if else statement, have you debug what happend with last row, what is the strName value?

Comment: Ok I see what you mean about eliminating the if/else statement.  That line by itself does the job. I've debugged on strName value when sort happens. The first iteration uses a blank strName and row count is -1. Then it processes that last row (Z's) with a row count of 0, next it processes the same name again, row count 1, then it moves to 2nd name, but row count is 1 again, then it goes back to first name, row count is 2 --it's so jacked I don't know how it even sorts correctly!  Is it possible I do not need the for loop in ItemDataBound event? With 100 rows I haven't been able to see last row

Comment: move this line code DataGrid1.DataSource = objDataView  before DataGrid1.DataBind() after if else statemets

Comment: Thanks for helping me give it a try but that made no difference.  Seems no matter what column I sort on (only allowing sort on 3 out of  8 columns,  (there are 100 rows exactly)), the last row always contains a button whether it should or not. I am at a loss.

Comment: you need to check what happend exactly with last row inside loop in ItemDataBound event

Comment: The for each loop is iterating through 10 rows then starts over again multiple times during debug. I think it's going to be infinite which is why I say I never get to the last row-I have been at it for 20 minutes still not done.  If I view in browser with no debugging  the page loads, albeit very slowly and with the last row showing a button no matter what.

Comment: ItemDataBound event fires for each row in your datasource, then you have a loop inside it, you should quit the loop and only work with current item e.Item

Comment: That did the trick! Oh.my.word. I can't believe it!! Thank you.  I was just about to cry when I saw your message and BINGO!  A million thanks!  I updated my code (#1) to reflect solution.  Please submit an ANSWER and I will accept it.

Comment: Sorry, but i was not sure about itemdatabound event, i believed it fires once, I havent work with aspx since 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it is ok to post the answer offered by DanielVorph. *“ItemDataBound event fires for each row in your datasource, then you have a loop inside it, you should quit the loop and only work with current item e.Item– DanielVorphMay 8 at 21:21” .*  In addition to this I  replaced `BoundColumn` in DataGrid1 with a `TemplateColumn`.

**VB.NET:**

```
Protected Sub DataGrid1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles DataGrid1.ItemDataBound

    'Get only non header or footer rows
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then

        Dim strName As String                               'column[2]
        Dim blnHasRecord As Boolean

        'get Name
        Dim lblName As Label = e.Item.FindControl("lblName")
        strName = lblName.Text.ToString()

        'query sql - does record exist for this Name?
        Dim oRecord As DataAccessLib.SqlConn = New DataAccessLib.SqlConn()
        blnHasRecord = oRecord. VerifyRecordExists (strName)

        'Show or hide button based on records existence
        DirectCast(e.Item.Cells(9).Controls(0), Button).Visible = blnHasRecord  'column[9]
    End If

End Sub
```

**ASPX:**
Remove this type of column:

```
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" Visible="False" />
```

Add this this type of column:

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label id="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval 
(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>'>
      </asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```